# Simple CRUD operation with PostgreSQL/MySQL in C# with Mono and Gtk#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, mono, gtk#

I'm starting out with Mono and C# and i'm looking for an example application that does a simple CRUD operation on a database. I have experience with web technologies (Rails, Django) and i wanted to get my head around desktop applications. Anyone has some links or even a tut? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood everything and I have never worked with mono but... I think it's the same way with .net framework, you could reference an assembly of PostgreSql or Mysql databases and build your app based with theses libs, using ado.net (NpgsqlConnection/MySqlConnection, NpgsqlCommand/MySqlCommand etc...) to do your crud operations.

Take a look at these links:

http://www.mono-project.com/PostgreSQL

http://www.mono-project.com/MySQL

You can download the right assembly and use it. I know the mono-project is compatible with .net framework 2.0, so, If I were you I would consider to use an ORM Tool, check here:

http://www.mono-project.com/Database_Access

I hope it helps :)

Comment: mono does quite a good chunk of .Net 4 now, nearly everything except bits of WCF and WPF.